# grab batch text content and put it in a variable

Tags: variables, batch-file

okay i have this command

```
netsh wlan show profiles
```

pretend that the wireless network that appears is named Zask.router

the prompt should appear something like this;

..........................................................

Profiles on interface wifi:

### group policy profiles (read only)

```
<none>
```

### user profiles

```
All User Profile     : Zask.router
```

..........................................................

is there any way i can get the content "Zask.router" to be placed in a variable?

okay thanks, new question. i changed the code to this;

```
for /f "tokens=4 delims=: " %%A in ('netsh wlan show profiles') do set "profile=%%A"
```

now i added this to the next line;

```
netsh wlan show profiles "%profile%" key=clear
```

then something that says "key content" (must be administrator) should appear with a wifi password next to it, how do i get that password to also go into a variable?
i tried doing something like this but it just displays the word "such" for some strange reason...

```
for /f "tokens=4 delims=: " %%A in ('netsh wlan show profiles') do set "profile=%%A
for /f "tokens=4 delims=: " %%A in ('netsh wlan show profiles "%profile%" key=clear') do set "profile2=%%A"
echo %profile2%
```

Comment: okay now for another question;

Comment: Please mark the solution as accepted if it works as you say (click the tick) and ask you new question as a new question. That's how the site works....

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the output you want is on the last line...

```
for /f "tokens=4 delims=: " %%A in ('netsh wlan show profiles') do set "YourVariable=%%A"
```

Use the "FOR /?" command to see help for FOR command. We are using it to split your lines into tokens separated by either spaces or :

- tokens=4 specifies that we want to save the 4th token
- delims=:(space) specifies that the characters ":" and " " are delimiters
- YourVariable is being set for every line in the output of the NETSH command. In this case, since we only care about the last line it works out without the need to compare text to find the desired line.

Comment: I edited my answer to include explanation. Study the FOR help. It will do a lot for you.

Comment: okay for some reason the command worked before but now its not, any reason why? i get an error stating %%A was unexpected at this time